# WebApi2 attribute routing URL format

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I would like to route with

```
api/prefix/{controller}/{id}/{param}
```

as opposed to

```
api/prefix?Controller={controller}&Id={id}&Param={param}
```

In other words, I would prefer a URL without the name/value parameters.

The controller is defined like this:

```
/// <summary>
/// Employee API
/// </summary>
[System.Web.Mvc.RoutePrefix("api/employee")]
public class EmployeeController : ApiController
{
    ///<summary>
    /// Returns a collection of employees from a supplied CSV of EmployeeIds
    /// </summary>
    /// <paramref name="EmployeeIds">CSV of EmployeeIds. Pass "ALL" to include all employees. Defaults to "ALL".</paramref>
    /// <paramref name="PageSize">Number of rows to return. Defaults to all rows</paramref>
    /// <paramref name="PageNumber">Number of the page to return. Defaults to Page 0</paramref>
    /// <returns>IEnumerable<Employee></returns>
    [System.Web.Mvc.Route("id/{EmployeeIDs:alpha?}/{PageSize:int?}/PageNum:int?}")]
    public IHttpActionResult getEmployeesByIds(string EmployeeIds = "ALL",int PageSize = 0,int PageNumber = 0)
    {
        EmployeeDb db = new EmployeeDb();
        IEnumerable<Employee> e = db.getEmployeesById(EmployeeIds, PageSize, PageNumber);
        return Ok(e);
    }
}
```

How can I control the way the format of the URL?

Comment: Unclear what you're asking. Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Why? `controller/action/` is much cleaner than `controller=mycontroller&action=myAction.....`

Comment: @Ric exactly, I want the former and am getting the latter.

Comment: You should use attribute routing from web api https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the System.Web.Mvc.RoutePrefix and the System.Web.Mvc.Route attributes, but you inherit from ApiController, so this is a Web API Controller, as opposed to an MVC Controller. 
Can you try switching over to System.Web.Http.RoutePrefix and System.Web.Http.Route?

Comment: Good catch, thanks! I made this change and am now getting an error message that a route template can't start with a "/" or "~". None of my templates start with anything non-alpha, so trying to track it down.

Comment: You have typos in the URL. The parameter names must match exactly the templateparts in the URL, and also there is a missing { before PageNum.
Try this 
[Route("id/{EmployeeIds:alpha?}/{PageSize:int?}/{PageNumber:int?}")]

Answer (score 1):

The `System.Web.Http` one is for Web API; the `System.Web.Mvc` one is for previous MVC versions. MVC is web applications, Web API is HTTP services.

RoutePrefix should be inherited from `System.Web.Http`.

As [ApiController](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.apicontroller(v=vs.118).aspx) is from System.Web.Http, it is not able to resolve your route.

This [ms-doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2) has good info about attribute routing.